# Concatenate Repeated Record in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data that exists in the following JSON structure

```
{"person": "John", "children": [{"name":"Tim", "age":9},{"name":"Suszan", "age":12},{"name":"Karl", "age":14}]}
```

and in Big Query, it has the schmea

```
children        RECORD  REPEATED    
children. age   INTEGER NULLABLE    
children. name  STRING  NULLABLE    
person          STRING  NULLABLE
```

When we look at the actual table, we have this

[image]

but I really would like to have the data in the following format

[image]

I'm stuck because I know I can use `unnest(children) as children` to have access to the record, but it creates an new row entirerly, but I can't use `ARRAY_TO_STRING(children.name)` because it's not purely an array. I'm kind of caught between the two.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the elements and aggregate that:

```
select t.person, string_agg(child, ',')
from t cross join
     unnest(children) child
group by t.person;
```

Comment: pefect! string_agg(child.name) is the only alteraton I had to make, but this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I appreciate it! I'll accept this as the answer as soon as the "asked question cooldown" passes

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest below version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT person, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(name) FROM t.children) AS children
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```